# Copy taxonomy terms from one post to another programmatically

Tags: php, posts, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

Let's say i have a post with post id `"1"` and post with post id `"2"`.

And i have a custom taxonomy named `"my_taxonomy"`.

The post with post id "1" has: `"term1","term2","term3"` selected for the `"my_taxonomy"` terms.

And the post with post id `"2"` has: `"term3","term4","term5"` selected for the `"my_taxonomy"` terms.

I want to programmatically copy the terms from first post to second so the post with post id `"2"` will have: `"term1","term2","term3"` selected for the `"my_taxonomy"` terms now.

How can i do that the most "short coded way" ?

**A note:** both posts are a custom post type posts.

I tried:

```
wp_set_object_terms( '2', wp_get_object_terms( '1', 'my_taxonomy' ), 'my_taxonomy');
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
wp_set_object_terms( 
    '2', 
    wp_get_object_terms( 
        '1', 
        'my_taxonomy', 
        array("fields"=>"ids") 
    ), 
   'my_taxonomy'
);
```

**Explanation:**

I added this: `,array("fields"=>"ids")` to the attempt i wrote in the question to make the `wp_get_object_terms` return array of ids alone (what the `wp_set_object_terms` want to get.